# startActivity not working on onCreateView

Tags: java

onCreateView

I created button click function called

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
Intent redirect = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MobileRecharge.class);
startActivity(redirect);`
}
```

Also Androidmainfest.xml also i created

```
<activity android:name=".MobileRecharge">
</activity>`
```

But when i am running code it is giving "Unfortunality application is stopped" error. Kindly help me in this regards.

Comment: please post the log cat...

Comment: Can you look at the LogCat and post the exception?

Comment: btnClick is in an Activity, or a Fragment?

Comment: btnclick activity just i create one text box & one button

Comment: Try this: `Intent redirect = new Intent(this, MobileRecharge.class);`

Comment: i done this but "The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<MobileRecharge>) is undefined" giving error like this

Comment: Have you tried only with `getActivity()`? Without `.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Ya i tried tht also but it is giving "unfortunality app stopped error"

Comment: onCreateView i added tht

Comment: btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
  
   @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
    
    
    Intent redirect = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MobileRecharge.class);
          startActivity(redirect);
          
    
    
    
            }
           
        });

Answer (score 0):

See the Log Cat: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #9: You must supply a layout_width attribute.` Check the MobileRechargue xml layout, in some `Layout` tag, you must specify `layout_width` attribute.

Comment: Can u plz tell me exactly